# cronR doesn't execute script in Rstudio server

Tags: r, cron, rstudio-server

I use a VPS which run a Rstudio server. I'd setup cron and the cronR packages.
When I create cron jobs for a Rscript. The cronTab seems to program it, but cron doesn't execute the script.

For example, this simple script which add a date stamp:

```
dated = data.frame(date = date())
dated2 = read.csv("date.csv",row.names = NULL)
dated = rbind(dated,dated2)
write.csv(dated,"date.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I create a cron job with cronR and check the crontab:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6050
## cronR job
## id:   essai2
## tags: 
## desc: I execute things
0-59 * * * * /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript '/home/pj/twittAnestProj/verif.R'  >> '/home/pj/twittAnestProj/verif.log' 2>&1
```

The script never starts (I had no add of date stamp in my scv file...)

Comment: I encountered a similar situation before. Usually, it is caused by using a relative path in your `read.csv` and `write.csv` functions. Consider changing that `data.csv` to its full path (something like `/home/pj/twittAnestProj/data.csv`).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It was a problem of relative path, which is different from the working path of r !

Comment: Glad to hear that. I have posted that comment as an answer. If you think that solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. There is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem before. Usually, it is caused by using a relative path in your `read.csv` and `write.csv` functions. Consider changing that `data.csv` to its full path (something like `/home/pj/twittAnestProj/data.csv`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the cron daemon is running as in `sudo cron start`